# Access object data in array list

Tags: java, arrays, list, object

I have an array list with three objects (Knight)

Now perhaps I want to access the color attribute of the second object, how do I do that?

when I use:

```
System.out.println(arraylist.toString());
```

I only get:

```
[Knight@28d93b30, Knight@1b6d3586, Knight@4554617c]
```

Comment: `arrayList.get(index)`

Comment: U can also override the toString method to receive a more representative string than 'Knight@28d93b30'

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` class contains the method `get(int)` which lets you specify a (zero-based) index and retrieve the corresponding item from the list.

To get the second object in your list you should use this:

```
Knight secondKnight = arrayList.get(1);
```

Then you can access any accessible methods or class fields defined by the `Knight` class, such as the colour.

(Because the index is zero-based, if you want to get the first `Knight` you would instead use `arrayList.get(0)`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `toString()` if you would like to output the colors of the Knights.

In order to do so you would want to do something like the following (similar to overriding the output operator in C++ if you're familiar with it).

```
// I'm assuming you have a Knight class, so in that class you would want 
// to override the toString() function

@Override
public String toString() {
    // Return a String of what you would like to output
    // Assuming the color is stored as a String already, return the color
    return this.getColor(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method I**

You must use the get(int i) method, which retrieves the object at the index of the array list, you can then access the fields of that object by using ".field".

Consider the following scenario which will be similar to what you are doing, you have a Knight class.

I will use an alien class:

```
public class Alien{

    //Properties of aliens
    int numOfFingers;
    String name;
    String color;

    public Alien(int num, String name, String color)
    {
        this.numOfFingers = num;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }       

}//End of alien class
```

The class containing the array list:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetailExtractor {

    //ArrayList containing alien objects
    static ArrayList<Alien> alienRegister = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Populating the arrayList
        alienRegister.add(new Alien(3, "Zorg", "Blue"));
        alienRegister.add(new Alien(5, "Chad", "Purple"));


        //Retrieving a property, say name of second alien...

        System.out.println(alienRegister.get(1).name);

    }

}
```

---

**METHOD II**

The reason you are not obtaining what you require from using the toString method is because you are printing an object, you need to override the toString method. If you print an object directly you will receive the objects hash code along with some other details...

What you must do is:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    //code to get required string followed by a return statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String color = arraylist.get(1).getColor();
```

This will work assuming you have some public getter for color in Knight class. Something like -

```
class Knight {
    ....
    String color;
    ....
    ....

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are printing with `System.out.println(arraylist.toString())` are the objects that the arraylist contains.

What you want to do, to access object two color is:

```
System.out.println(arraylist.getIndex(0).getColor);
```

The `getColor` is assuming that you have a getter for the color property